# The remote name could not be resolved: 'graph.microsoft.com' Proxy IIS

Tags: asp.net-mvc, microsoft-graph-api

I have implemented an Azure Active directory app using Microsoft Graph API.
It works very well as expected in the Local Dev machine which works on IIS express.

Now I want to move the web to IIS and when deployed the `WebRequest` which talks to `graph.microsoft.com` throws an exception:

> The remote name could not be resolved: 'graph.microsoft.com' at
>   System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse() at

As I am behind the corporate proxy, I am routing the request throe below means.

In the code..

1st way:

```cs
IWebProxy webProxy = new WebProxy("http://{proxy url}:8080", true);
webProxy.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
request.Proxy = webProxy;
```

2nd way:

```cs
IWebProxy webProxy = WebRequest.GetSystemWebProxy();
request.Proxy = webProxy;

request.Method = "GET";
request.Accept = "application/json";
request.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " + token);

var response = request.GetResponse();
using(var reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
{
    responseContent = reader.ReadToEnd();
}
```

I have placed the below proxy configuration in the `web.conig`:

```xml
<system.net>
    <defaultProxy>
        <proxy usesystemdefault="True" 
               proxyaddress="http://{proxy url}:8080" 
               bypassonlocal="True"></proxy>
    </defaultProxy>
</system.net>
```

Nothing works and I continue to get the exception `The remote name could not be resolved:'graph.microsoft.com'`

Comment: The URI for Graph should be `https://graph.microsoft.com/`. You're proxy is using `http`. I've not tried using a proxy with Graph but I suspect this will cause issues.

Comment: No. it has nothing to do with https. I believe this issue is something related to app pool identity